# Python Fit circle with center outside of image

Tags: python, image-processing, geometry, opencv

I have the following binary image of a disk, and extracted the border of it:
[image: Binary image of disk]
[image: Border]
How can I calculate the center and the radius of the circle? I already tried some methods with cv2.HoughCircles() and  cv2.findContours() + cv2.fitEllipse(), however these don't work with images where the circle center is far outside of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find center of circle from 3 points, but for robust solution it is better to use ransac method. It uses a set of different solutions, for all your bounding points set and will give you more accurate solution. For instance check : [here](https://github.com/SeongHyunBae/RANSAC-circle-python)